# Visual Studio Context Menu - Register Assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I right click a class library project (the project node) I see an entry 'Register Assembly'.

Does anyone know what this command does? I would guess it registers the assembly in the GAC (but that requires strong name) but I would prefer to know more about it instead of experimenting to find out.

If this is not out of the box Visual Studio how can I easily find out where it comes from?

I tried googling and didn't find too much.

Comment: I have created a new class library project but don't see a 'Register Assembly' menu choice.  What project type is it e.g. old school COM dll?  Do you have some extension installed that is creating this menu choice?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out! I've only found two web pages on it. One was code maid and they said it's not them and to post on msdn. The other was complaining about how it was at the bottom and the folks were requesting it be moved from the bottom. Is there any simple way to find out which extension it comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry is from the Visual Studio Data Lake Tools and should't be on C# projects. It's a bug as you can read here:

> Thanks for reaching to us and really sorry for putting this entry for any C# projects. As a temporary workaround, you can go to Program and Files (in Windows) and search "Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio", and you can uninstall the plugin there (as we are using MSI installer so you cannot uninstall it from VS).
>
> That "Register Assembly" button is for Data Lake users - and since we are integrating the Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio with Azure SDK which has a big installation base, it brings this confusion. We are sorry for this - and we will improve this further.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7313781e-6fda-43c2-bd9c-52318da0bdb8/visual-studio-data-lake-tools-extension-crashes-visual-studio-20152?forum=AzureDataLake